# Automatically populate title field

Tags: plugins

I have a WordPress website with Gravity Forms and people can share YouTube videos on it. (The form can be found here: http://shareminecraftvideos.com)

Now what I want is to automatically take the video title and use it as the title for the post. I have been searching Google and tried things, but nothing worked so far. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So after the video URL is pasted into the form it pulls the title?

Comment: Have you contacted Gravity Forms support? 3rd party plugins are offtopic here, can you explain why this requires WordPress specific knowledge, rather than Gravity Forms specific knowledge?

Comment: Josh, yes that is essentially what I need it to do.